# IIS URL rewrite not working properly 404 errors

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, pattern-matching

I am  upgrading a joomla website setup on IIS 10. Now I have oldsite.com and a newsite.com. My new site has slightly different folder structure but page names and content is same. Rightly so client doesn't want to lose SEO ranking on the old pages and want to redirect them to correct one on the new upgraded site.

i need to do following

- is wildcard and will get replaced with whatever will be typed in the URL in it’s place

  /div-services/* will redirect to /div/*

  /div-questions/* will redirect to /div/questions/*

  /fm-lw-services/* will redirect to /fm-lw/*

  /locations/* will redirect to /contact/*

  /resources/blog/* will redirect to /blog/*

  /contact-us/* will redirect to /contact/*

I initially setup my pattern to

```
(.*)(div-services)(.*) becomes {R:1}( div){R:1}
```

It worked well till I have matching phrase to repeat in some form in the url. which in this case is “div-services” coming again in the URL, it gets replaced as well.

For example if the url is newsite.com/div-services/xyz/abc-div-services then per the rule it will replace both occurrences of “div-services” which is not desired I only need to replace the first occurrence. I though it’s a easy fix and made my pattern as following

`(.*)(/div-services/)(.*) replace to {R:1}(/div/){R:1}`

Even though in the test pattern it validates with success but it just doesn’t work and does not re write the URL I even tried with the escape character

`(.*)(\/div-services\/)(.*) becomes {R:1}(/div/){R:1}`

Still no luck. After digging and digging I found following example

```
div-services/(.*)$ becomes div/{R:1}
```

this worked generally well but now if I don’t have the ending forward slash it won’t work

for example if URL is is newsite.com/div-services it won’t work but is newsite.com/div-services/ and is newsite.com/div-services/xyx will work fine.

I am just at loss, any help will be much appreciated. I just don’t understand why can’t I detect the forward slash /

Comment: fyi I figured why this was not working (.*)(\/div-services\/)(.*) becomes {R:1}(/div/){R:1}

Answer (score 0):

fyi I figured why this was not working `(.*)(/div-services/)(.*) becomes {R:1}(/div/){R:1}`

it is because input start the after the first forward slash, i was assuming that it would be the whole URL that is why my regular expression validates but actually doesn't work. As when it run it is only taking URL after the first slash, that clarifies so many things and logical explanation on why many of my patterns were not working even though they would pass the pattern test. Hopefully it save others the hours and hours i wasted because i didn't have clear understand how it was working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqLy7.png)